# error using doctrine:build --all symfony 1.4.4 apostrophe trunk

Tags: symfony1, doctrine

I'm stumped on why when I do doctrine:build -all it throws 2 warnings.
I've tried commenting out all the schema.yml files and it still throws it.
Anyone better informed help me understand where it is coming from, is there some caching I am unaware of?

I've deleted the cache (./symfony cc). Manually deleted all the lib/ models, forms, filters tasks so that there isn't anything hanging around and to no avail. I can't find anything on google for the error so I'm pretty stuck, I want to understand where the error is coming from, it's very early on in the process so I presume it is yaml related but I don't know how to track down where.

Cheers,

Paul

Shell output section Below:

> > doctrine  generating model classes
> >     PHP Warning:  array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array in /mnt/Target01/338166/www.example.co.uk/web/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/task/sfDoctrineBaseTask.class.php on line 182
> >     PHP Stack trace:
> >     PHP   1. {main}() /mnt/Target01/338166/www.example.co.uk/web/symfony:0
> >     PHP   2. include() /mnt/Target01/338166/www.example.co.uk/web/symfony:14
> >     PHP   3. sfSymfonyCommandApplication->run() /mnt/Target01/338166/www.example.co.uk/web/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/command/cli.php:20
> >     PHP   4. sfTask->runFromCLI() /mnt/Target01/338166/www.example.co.uk/web/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/command/sfSymfonyCommandApplication.class.php:76
> >     PHP   5. sfBaseTask->doRun() /mnt/Target01/338166/www.example.co.uk/web/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/task/sfTask.class.php:97
> >     PHP   6. sfDoctrineBuildTask->execute() /mnt/Target01/338166/www.example.co.uk/web/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/task/sfBaseTask.class.php:68
> >     PHP   7. sfTask->run() /mnt/Target01/338166/www.example.co.uk/web/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/task/sfDoctrineBuildTask.class.php:156
> >     PHP   8. sfBaseTask->doRun() /mnt/Target01/338166/www.example.co.uk/web/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/task/sfTask.class.php:173
> >     PHP   9. sfDoctrineBuildModelTask->execute() /mnt/Target01/338166/www.example.co.uk/web/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/task/sfBaseTask.class.php:68
> >     PHP  10. sfDoctrineBaseTask->prepareSchemaFile() /mnt/Target01/338166/www.example.co.uk/web/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/task/sfDoctrineBuildModelTask.class.php:67
> >     PHP  11. array_merge() /mnt/Target01/338166/www.example.co.uk/web/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/task/sfDoctrineBaseTask.class.php:182

Warning: array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array in /mnt/Target01/338166/www.example.co.uk/web/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/task/sfDoctrineBaseTask.class.php on line 182

Call Stack:
    0.0008      47204   1. {main}() /mnt/Target01/338166/www.example.co.uk/web/symfony:0
    0.0136     279748   2. include('/mnt/Target01/338166/www.example.co.uk/web/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/command/cli.php') /mnt/Target01/338166/www.example.co.uk/web/symfony:14
    0.9075    7815564   3. sfSymfonyCommandApplication->run() /mnt/Target01/338166/www.example.co.uk/web/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/command/cli.php:20
    0.9419    7817164   4. sfTask->runFromCLI() /mnt/Target01/338166/www.example.co.uk/web/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/command/sfSymfonyCommandApplication.class.php:76
    0.9433    7818056   5. sfBaseTask->doRun() /mnt/Target01/338166/www.example.co.uk/web/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/task/sfTask.class.php:97
    1.0198    8445008   6. sfDoctrineBuildTask->execute() /mnt/Target01/338166/www.example.co.uk/web/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/task/sfBaseTask.class.php:68
    2.0900    9762304   7. sfTask->run() /mnt/Target01/338166/www.example.co.uk/web/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/task/sfDoctrineBuildTask.class.php:156
    2.0907    9764724   8. sfBaseTask->doRun() /mnt/Target01/338166/www.example.co.uk/web/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/task/sfTask.class.php:173
    2.0926    9766452   9. sfDoctrineBuildModelTask->execute() /mnt/Target01/338166/www.example.co.uk/web/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/task/sfBaseTask.class.php:68
    2.1560    9789556  10. sfDoctrineBaseTask->prepareSchemaFile() /mnt/Target01/338166/www.example.co.uk/web/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/task/sfDoctrineBuildModelTask.class.php:67
    4.3235   10119764  11. array_merge() /mnt/Target01/338166/www.example.co.uk/web/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/task/sfDoctrineBaseTask.class.php:182

> > file+     /tmp/doctrine_schema_70082.yml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just stumbled over the same error.  I had an error in my schema.yml by definining an empty table name:

```
SomeTableNameThatShouldHaveBeenRemoved:
SomeOtherTableName:
  colums:
    id: etc. pp
```

Rather easy to spot one would think, yet when such a vague warning is thrown ...